# Erro ao salvar formulário com hibernate: could not execute statement

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

Estou com um formulário web que salva dados no MySql, mas está retornando um erro `could not execute statement`; `Column 'bairro' cannot be null`. O erro diz que o campo 'bairro' não pode ser nulo, porém estou preenchendo todos os campos. Fiz um teste, mudei o campo 'coluna' para nullable = true, preenchi o campo, e no banco está salvando NOT NULL, ou seja, não está passando o o valor preenchido.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" lang="pt-br">

<ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">
 <ui:define name="conteudo">
  <h1>Novo aluno</h1>

  <div id="infoMensager">(mensagem de sucesso ou erro)</div>

  <br />

  <form jsf:id="form">
   <!-- borda que delimita campos / ctr + f => substitui-->
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Dados pessoais</legend>
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label> <br /> 
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.nome}" id="nome" /> <br /> 
    <label for="sexo">Sexo:</label><br />
    <select jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.sexo}" id="sexo" size="0">
     <f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.sexos}"/>
    </select><br /> 
    <label for="cpf">CPF:</label> <br /> 
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.cpf}" id="cpf" /> <br /> 
    <label for="rg">RG:</label> <br /> 
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.rg}" id="rg" /> <br /> 
    <label for="dataNascimento">Data de Nascimento:</label> <br /> 
    <input type="date" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.dataNascimento}" id="dataNascimento">
     <f:convertDateTime type="localDate" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    </input>
   </fieldset>

   <br />

   <fieldset>
    <legend>Situação</legend>
    <label for="situacao">Situação:</label><br /> 
    <select jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.situacao}" id="situacao" size="0">
     <f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.situacoes}"/>
    </select>
   </fieldset>

   <br />

   <fieldset>
    <legend>Endereço</legend>
    <label for="rua">Rua:</label> <br /> 
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.endereco.rua}" id="rua" /> <br />  
    <label for="numero">Número:</label> <br />
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.endereco.numero}" id="numero" /> <br /> 
    <label for="complemento">Complemento:</label> <br /> 
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.endereco.complemento}" id="complemento" /> <br /> 
    <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label> <br /> 
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.endereco.cidade}" id="cidade" /> <br /> 
    <label for="estado">Estado:</label><br />
    <select jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.endereco.estado.sigla}" id="estado" size="0">
     <f:selectItems value="#{dataBean.estados}" var="e" itemLabel="#{e.nome}" itemValue="#{e.sigla}"/>
    </select><br />
    <label for="cep">CEP:</label> <br />
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.endereco.cep}" id="cep" /><br />
    <label for="bairro">Bairro:</label><br/>  
    <input type="text" jsf:valeu="#{alunoBean.aluno.endereco.bairro}" id="bairro"/>
   </fieldset>

   <br />

   <fieldset>
    <legend>Contato</legend>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label><br /> 
    <input type="text" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.contato.email}" id="email" /><br /> 
    <label for="telefoneCelularDDD">Telefone celular:</label> <br />
    <input type="tel" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.contato.dddCelular}" id="telefoneCelularDDD" />&#160;
    <input type="tel" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.contato.numeroCelular}" id="telefoneCelularNumero" /><br/>
    <label for="telefoneFixoDDD">Telefone fixo:</label> <br />
    <input type="tel" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.contato.dddfixo}" id="telefoneFixoDDD" />&#160;
    <input type="tel" jsf:value="#{alunoBean.aluno.contato.numeroFixo}" id="telefoneFixoNumero" />
   </fieldset>

   <br />
   
   <input type="submit" value="Gravar" jsf:action="#{alunoBean.gravar}"/>&#160;
   <input type="button" value="Relatório de acesso" />
  </form>
 </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

```js
package br.com.jopaulo.sistemacad.domain.aluno;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Embeddable
public class Endereco implements Serializable {

 @Column(name = "rua", nullable = false, length = 128)
 private String rua;

 @Column(name = "numero", nullable = false, length = 6)
 private Integer numero;

 @Column(name = "complemento", nullable = true, length = 64)
 private String complemento;

 @Column(name = "cidade", nullable = false, length = 64)
 private String cidade;

 @Column(name = "cep", nullable = false, length = 8)
 private Integer cep;

 @Column(name = "bairro", nullable = false, length = 32)
 private String bairro;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "estado_id", nullable = false)
 private Estado estado = new Estado();

 public String getRua() {
  return rua;
 }

 public void setRua(String rua) {
  this.rua = rua;
 }

 public Integer getNumero() {
  return numero;
 }

 public void setNumero(Integer numero) {
  this.numero = numero;
 }

 public String getComplemento() {
  return complemento;
 }

 public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
  this.complemento = complemento;
 }

 public String getCidade() {
  return cidade;
 }

 public void setCidade(String cidade) {
  this.cidade = cidade;
 }

 public Integer getCep() {
  return cep;
 }

 public void setCep(Integer cep) {
  this.cep = cep;
 }

 public String getBairro() {
  return bairro;
 }

 public void setBairro(String bairro) {
  this.bairro = bairro;
 }

 public Estado getEstado() {
  return estado;
 }

 public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
  this.estado = estado;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Endereco [rua=" + rua + ", numero=" + numero + ", complemento=" + complemento + ", cidade=" + cidade
    + ", cep=" + cep + ", bairro=" + bairro + ", estado=" + estado + ", getRua()=" + getRua()
    + ", getNumero()=" + getNumero() + ", getComplemento()=" + getComplemento() + ", getCidade()="
    + getCidade() + ", getCep()=" + getCep() + ", getBairro()=" + getBairro() + ", getEstado()="
    + getEstado() + ", hashCode()=" + hashCode() + ", getClass()=" + getClass() + ", toString()="
    + super.toString() + "]";
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + ((bairro == null) ? 0 : bairro.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((cep == null) ? 0 : cep.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((cidade == null) ? 0 : cidade.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((complemento == null) ? 0 : complemento.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((estado == null) ? 0 : estado.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((numero == null) ? 0 : numero.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((rua == null) ? 0 : rua.hashCode());
  return result;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  if (this == obj)
   return true;
  if (obj == null)
   return false;
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
   return false;
  Endereco other = (Endereco) obj;
  if (bairro == null) {
   if (other.bairro != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!bairro.equals(other.bairro))
   return false;
  if (cep == null) {
   if (other.cep != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!cep.equals(other.cep))
   return false;
  if (cidade == null) {
   if (other.cidade != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!cidade.equals(other.cidade))
   return false;
  if (complemento == null) {
   if (other.complemento != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!complemento.equals(other.complemento))
   return false;
  if (estado == null) {
   if (other.estado != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!estado.equals(other.estado))
   return false;
  if (numero == null) {
   if (other.numero != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!numero.equals(other.numero))
   return false;
  if (rua == null) {
   if (other.rua != null)
    return false;
  } else if (!rua.equals(other.rua))
   return false;
  return true;
 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá!
Da uma revisada no seu código, mais precisamente aqui:

```html
<input type="text" jsf:valeu="#{alunoBean.aluno.endereco.bairro}" id="bairro"/>
```

Você trocou o value por valeu!

Comment: Muito bem notado, obrigado.